# Is making network calls in UICollectionView.willDisplay bad practise?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am making an Demo APP which fetches images from a RESTFul service and displays it in a `UICollectionView`

So I am making the Network Calls to fetch the image in `willDisplay` delegate method.

But In a WWDC talk about `UICollectionView` the presenter say's all the heavy lifting for configuring the cell must done in `cellForItemAt` method of the datasource and minimal configuration should be done in the `willDisplay` method.

But making Network Calls in the datasource doesn't feel right as I'll have to wait for the network call to complete before I dequeue the cell.

Can anybody point out the pros and cons of both approaches.

And which method will be the best place to make Network calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place is in `cellForItemAt` , as it's being called earlier than `willDisplayCell` which has the benefit of time , aslo you don't have to wait as the image is downloaded asynchronously say with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) OR [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) aslo it's cached for you , so if the user scrolls fastly the download will not occur again for the same image